# Capturing microphone audio using Naudio + WASAPI?

Tags: capture, microphone, naudio, bass, wasapi

I am looking for an example code on how to capture microphone audio using Naudio + WASAPI.

(I am not interested in direct to disk recording, what i need is to process the input buffer in realtime in order to do some audio effects.)

I've searched a lot, but could not find any decent sample online.

Can you please help?

P.S. BASS library and C# examples are welcome as well!

Answer (score 4):

The [NAudio source code](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.txt) comes with a demo app that shows how to capture audio using WASAPI. Look in `NAudioDemo\RecordingDemo\RecordingPanel.cs`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen that example, but it seems that the buffer size is constantly changing (7000-8000 bytes.)

Is there a way to modify this code to make the buffer constant size?

Comment: I think that is an artefact of the way WASAPI is implemented. You could break the buffers up into chunks yourself if you need constant size.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a lot of code samples, though not covering NAudio they do have a few samples that show in detail how to use the Windows Audio Session API.

Since WASAPI is a native-only API there are both sample projects that show you how to use that API from a native-only app [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Audio-Session-ea894455) as well as samples that show you how to build a native component that wraps the API for consumption from a CSharp application. I couldn't find the direct link to the C#/C++-sample but it's included in the [Windows 8 App Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-app-samples-3bea89c8) package. Then there's the option of writing a managed wrapper for the API altogether but unless you enjoy pain and are looking for an adventure in marshaling I wouldn't recommend it...

If you're developing for Windows Phone then there's a VOIP-sample in the WP8 SDK that covers how to capture and render PCM audio data using WASAPI.

As Mark pointed out, the size of the pcm data buffer might differ over time and this is in part due to the fact that WASAPI is a low-latency Audio API and therefore has as little abstraction between the consumer (your app) and the producer (the driver) as possible. Though there's nothing that stops you from doing some fixes size buffering of your own and only pass on the data to your app when your own buffer is full.